# Module Routing For Application

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have he following url for my codeigniter application and I'm trying to find out how I can view this specific controller with the url. The my-project is what is used for my cms and the "admin" url segment is a variable representing a section of the cms area, "users" is the module from which I need to get the admin.php file for. I am using the wiredesignz 3rd page HMVC plugin into this application.

testsitehere.com/my-project/admin/users

```
-application
    -modules
        -users
            -controllers
                admin.php
```

I have tried the following route but still received the 404 error page.

```
$route['my-project/:any/:any'] = '$1/$2/admin';
```

What am I doing wrong for it to not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use brackets:

$route['my-project/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$1/$2/admin';